# Extending ArrayObject: Why does get_object_vars return an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, arrayobject

Given the following class, why does `get_object_vars` return an empty array? This only happens when I'm extending PHP's `ArrayObject` but in the documentation I can't manage to find out the reason for this behavior.

```
class Test extends ArrayObject
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    public function setFooBarValues( array $values )
    {
        $this->foo  = !empty( $values['foo'] ) ? $values['foo'] : null;
        $this->bar  = !empty( $values['bar'] ) ? $values['bar'] : null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars( $this );
    }
}
```

Running the following code that first sets the object's values shows that `get_object_vars` does not return the object's properties.

```
$object = new Test( array( 'lemon' => 1, 'orange' => 2, 'banana' => 3, 'apple' => 4 ) );
$object->setFooBarValues( array( 'foo' => 'x', 'bar' => 'y' ) );
var_dump( $object->getArrayCopy() );
```

Expected result:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(1) "x"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(1) "y"
}
```

Actual result:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the reason is not explained in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#class.arrayobject) the object seems to handle all its properties internally. Take a look at the constructor's second parameter `int $flags = 0` and the two flags [provided in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#arrayobject.constants.flags):

- **ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST**
  Properties of the object have their normal functionality when accessed as list (var_dump, foreach, etc.).
- **ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS**
  Entries can be accessed as properties (read and write).

The constant `STD_PROP_LIST` is what you want to use for standard property access. Supplying the constructor with this constant will give you the result you are looking for:

```
$object = new Test(
    array( 'lemon' => 1, 'orange' => 2, 'banana' => 3, 'apple' => 4 ),
    ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST
);
$object->setValues( array( 'foo' => 'x', 'bar' => 'y' ) );
var_dump( $object->getArrayCopy() );
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(1) "x"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(1) "y"
}
```